# Does every policy installed must come from a package? (express-gateway)

Tags: express-gateway

I read the documentation and I wonder if the only way to install policies (under plugin) is from package?

I know that I can create a local package and install it as a file but I wonder if I missed a way to just create my specific policy (for example, under 'policies' folder, next to 'config') and install it at the gateway, without any NPM intervention.

So is there a way or I missed a point?

Answer (score 1):

you can definitely load your plugins and policy directly without having to pass through NPM.

All you need to do is specify the package file location in the plugin definition, in `system.config.yml` file.

You can see an example of such technique [here](https://github.com/ExpressGateway/express-gateway-plugin-rewrite/blob/master/test/config/system.config.yml#L7-L9)

I hope that clarifies!